# Working with custom annotations in the Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, httpresponse

I got the response body from the `HttpServletResponse` with `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` used.

Now, I introduced custom annotations for the entities fields in my app and I need response body returned without the fields that I have annotated.

I do not want to affect my application behavior.

For example:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{
....

@Column
private String firstname;

@MyCustomAnnotation
@Column
private String lastname;
...
```

The real response body for the client should look like:

```
{"firstname":"John", "lastname":"Smith"}
```

And response body that I need for my later work is:

```
{"firstname":"John", "lastname":"MyCustomAnnotation"}
```

or

```
 {"firstname":"John"}
```

or similar.

I was wondering if it is possible to do such a thing? Can I get one version of the response(filtered) and send client real version of the response?

I would like to avoid changing of the application code (methods in the controllers, model etc.), if it's possible. I would like to do all my work in the class where I am dealing with the HttpServletResponse.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need are [json views](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation), or if you simply want to ignore a field in your response - then @JsonIgnore